# How to check column name of clicked cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have `dataGridView` and `CellDoubleClick` event.

I need to do some actions when cell is clicked two times but it must be cell in a column with a specific name. I don't have any idea how to check column name.

**P.S. `dataGridView` must have `SelectionMode = FullRowSelect`**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( /*check column name*/ )
        {
            // actions
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from the event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
    
        string columnName = this.dataGridViewName.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
        if ( columnName )
        {
            // actions
        }
    }
```

you can get the index with

```
 int columnIndex = dGVTransGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
```